# Is $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(x) dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Is it true that

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(x) dx$$

Just making sure.

If not, how about:

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = (f(b)-f(a))b - \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)dx$$

I'm having a hard time concentrating right now, and I'm trying to figure out how to get the area under a curve when the function is inverted.

Comment: You may be interested in [Young's inequality for increasing functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality#Standard_version_for_increasing_functions).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For what it's worth, here's a diagram to  accompany   Brian M. Scott's and Leandro's answers:

[image]

Comment: I am curious: what program did you use for drawing this illustration?

Comment: @J.D. http://jsxgraph.org/

Comment: This owuld be much better as an addition to his answer, rather than competing against it.

Answer (score 24):

No, but there is a relationship between those two quantities if $f$ is continuously differentiable and strictly increasing (you can relax the last assumption).

By parts, we have $\int_a^b f(x)dx = x f(x)|_a^b - \int_a^b x f'(x)dx = x f(x)|_a^b - \int_a^b f^{-1}(f(x)) f'(x)dx$ = $x f(x)|_a^b - \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(u) du $ where in the last step we do the substitution $u=f(x)$.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. No need to bring geometry in. Upvoted.

Comment: Furthermore, we can get $\int_a^b f(x)dx = x f(x)|_a^b - \int_a^b x f'(x)dx = x f(x)|_a^b - \int_a^b f^{-1}(f(x)) f'(x)dx=x f(x)|_a^b - \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(u) du(u=f(x))=x f(x)|_a^b - \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(x) dx $, so your guess is close to the fact that $\int_a^b f(x) dx = bf(b)-af(a) - \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)dx$

Comment: @Huang You just wrote the same as him. (?)

Comment: @Peter Because the op guessed $\int_a^b f(x) dx = (f(b)-f(a))b - \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)dx$ , I just wan to show him his guess is close to the fact.

Comment: Also when the function f and its inverse are analytic in a domain about the origin including b, the results are related to the Legendre transformation with f(0)=0 and a=0.

Answer (score 12):

No. Take $f(x) = x^2$, $a = 0$, $b = 1$. Then in this interval $f$ is integrable and invertible, with $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{x}$, but the integrals are easily seen to be different.

Comment: My vote here helped you jump from 998 to 1008!

Comment: @math101 hey, thanks! :)

Answer (score 9):

You actually have that:

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = b f(b) - a f(a) - \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1} (x) dx $$

Here's a graph:

[image]

The rectangle $ObCB$ has area $b\cdot f(b)$. The rectangle $OaDA$ has area $a \cdot f(a)$. The curved trapezium $ADCB$ has area $\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1} (x) dx $ so it is expected that:

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \mathcal{A}(ObCB) - \mathcal{A}(OaDA) - \mathcal{A}(ADCB)$$
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = b f(b) - a f(a) - \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1} (x) dx $$

which is actually true.

Remeber that the starting function has to be one-to-one and onto for the inverse to be defined.

You can check a full proof in Michael Spivak's Calculus (though he want's you to do it, he provides the steps necessary to do so).

Answer (score 4):

No.

Suppose that $f(x)$ is a continuous, strictly increasing function on $[a,b]$. Then $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ gives the area between the curve and that segment $[a,b]$ on the $x$-axis, while $\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)dx$ gives the area between the curve and the segment $[f(a),f(b)]$ on the $y$-axis, and it’s easy to see that these two areas need not be the same. (There are easy concrete examples $-$ I see now that Leandro has given one $-$ but even a few pictures should convince you.)

Answer (score -1):

∫baf(x)dx + ∫f(b)f(a)f−1(x)dx = bf(b)-af(a) is the expression to be used. The proof of the same can be seen here

[Prove that $\int_a^bf(x)dx+ \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(y)dy=bf(b)-af(a)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562960/prove-that-int-abfxdx-int-fafb-f-1ydy-bfb-afa)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).