# Show: $ f(a) = a,\ f(b) = b \implies \int_a^b \left[ f(x) + f^{-1}(x) \right] \, \mathrm{d}x = b^2 - a^2 $

Tags: calculus, integration

> If $a,b$ are fixed points of $f$, then $$ \int_a^b \left[ f(x) + f^{-1}(x) \right] \, \mathrm{d}x = b^2 - a^2 $$

In the words of 2014 MIT Integration Bee Champion (Carl Lian), the above property was responsible for the champion's victory in the 2013 MIT Integration Bee. How does one go about proving this property?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106509/is-int-ab-fx-dx-int-fafb-f-1x-dy

Comment: Do you know that $f(a) = a$ and $f(b) = b$ for this problem?

Comment: Is there no condition on $f$? It seems unlikely to be true for any $f$.

Comment: You guys are absolutely right, I missed the fact that $a,b$ must be fixed points of $f$. Thank you!

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562960/prove-that-int-abfxdx-int-fafb-f-1ydy-bfb-afa

Comment: For *why* this is true, draw a picture.

Comment: Uou obviously need $f(x)$ $1-1$ and onto for the question to even make sense, of coruse.

Comment: It seems the links @JimmyK4542 posted answer my question. If you want to convert the comments to a full answer, I'll upvote/accept.

Comment: Yes, this is essentially a visual result. Curious how it works out if $a<0<b$, visually, but $0\leq a<b$ is visually obvious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's assume that $f$ is monotonic and differentiable. Using the substitution $y = f(x)$ followed by integration by parts, we get:

$\displaystyle\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(y)\,dy = \int_{a}^{b}xf'(x)\,dx = \left[xf(x)\right]_{a}^{b} - \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx = [bf(b)-af(a)] - \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx + \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)\,dx = bf(b)-af(a)$.

If we also know that $f(a) = a$ and $f(b) = b$, this becomes: $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}\left[f(x)+f^{-1}(x)\right]\,dx = b^2-a^2$.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Geometric method]

The area of the two colored regions are $b^2-a^2$ (difference of areas of two rectangles)

$$b(b-a)+a(b-a)=b^2-a^2$$

Answer (score 0):

It is known that $$\int f^{-1}(x)dx=xf^{-1}(x)-F(f^{-1}(x))+C$$Where $F(x)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x)$. Substituting, we get $$I=\int_a^bf(x)+f^{-1}(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)+bf^{-1}(b)-F(f^{-1}(b))-af^{-1}(a)+F(f^{-1}(a))$$Since $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$, $f^{-1}(a)=a$ and likewise for $b$. So, substituting this in: $$I=F(b)-F(a)+b^2-F(b)-a^2+F(a)=b^2-a^2$$