# $\int_0^1\bigl( f(x)+f^{-1}(x )\bigr)\>dx=1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

Given any strictly-increasing continuous function $f$ such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, show that $$\int_0^1 [f(x)+f^{-1}(x) ]dx= 1.$$

I tried using mean value theorem but it won't work. I tried few examples it is correct.

Edit:

If I draw  graph of picture, and seeing integral as area, we can see the integral is just area of the square $\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)\}$.

Please give me a hint to attack this problem analytically.

Comment: The inverse is the function $f$ but reflected at $y=x$, if I recall correctly. I think it may be of help.

Comment: Draw a graph. Consider the geometric meaning of integrals.

Comment: @xbh,@sisyphus,thanks,  i got geometric idea , I'm looking for analytical ways .

Comment: If you are allowed to use conclusions from **Riemann-Stieltjes** integration, then the theorem of *change variables* and *integration by parts* would work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show: $f(a) = a,f(b) = b \implies \int_a^b \left[ f(x) + f^{-1}(x) \right] \, \mathrm{d}x = b^2 - a^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906521/show-fa-a-fb-b-implies-int-ab-left-fx-f-1x-right)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the change of variables theorem, if $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is differentiable then
$$\int_0^1f^{-1}(x)\,dx=\int_{f(0)}^{f(1)}f^{-1}(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}f^{-1}(f(x))f'(x)\,dx=$$
$$=\int_0^1 xf'(x)\,dx=[xf(x)]_0^1-\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=1-\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$$
using integration by parts

Comment: If $f$ isn't absolutely continuous this won't work.

Comment: @UmbertoP. thanks for the note! Could differentiable + strictly increasing imply absolute continuity?

Comment: Unfortunately not. If $g$ is any nondecreasing non-AC function, then $x \mapsto x+g(x)$ is strictly increasing but not AC.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mu$ is two dimensional Lebesgue measure then $1=\mu (0,1) \times (0,1))=\mu \{(x,y): y\leq f(x)\} + \mu \{(x,y): y> f(x)\}=\mu \{(x,y): y\leq f(x)\} + \mu \{(x,y): x <f^{-1}(y)\}$.

Use Fubini's Theorem to see that the first term is $\int_0^{1} f(x)dx$ and the second term is $\int_0^{1}f^{-1}(y)dy$.

Comment: Didn't expect ISI professor here . Thanks sir

Comment: This proof is analytical as asked by OP. Why the downvote?