# integral involving invertible functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be an increasing invertible function.
Prove that $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)dx=bf(b)-af(a)$$
We have proved by a variable shift in the second integral.
It comes like $\int_{a}^{b}(f(x)+xf'(x))dx.$

But it unclear as to how the increasing property helps.
Also we tried using geometry and compute the areas but failed.

Comment: Actually I would like if there is some geometric proof of the original integral.

Comment: Geometric? Interesting. Mind if I steal that idea? and post a question with some analysis of my own?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\int_{a}^{b}(f(x)+xf'(x))dx$$

Let $y=xf(x)$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=xf'(x)+f(x)$$

Thus our integral becomes,

$$\int_{x=a}^{x=b}dy.$$

$$bf(b)-af(a)$$

The increasing property seems misleading, there is no need for it.

---

As per OP's request here is a graphical explanation from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106524/127574) by David Mitra.

[image]

This is so brilliant, no explanation required.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Since $y=f(x)$ is invertible, the function $x=f^{-1}(y)$ is defined, $x=a\iff y=f(a)$ and $x=b\iff y=f(b)$. Thus
$$\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(y)dy=\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} xdy=\int_a^b (x \frac{dy}{dx}) dx=\int_a^b x f'(x) dx$$
Now, it is clear that $(xf(x))'=f(x)+xf'(x)$ and hence it is easy to complete.