# Proof without words for $\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^i\frac{1}{2i+1}$

Tags: summation, pi, alternative-proof

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^i\frac{1}{2i+1}$$

$$1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\frac19-\cdots=\frac\pi4$$

Does anyone know of a **proof without words** for this? I am not looking a for a *just any* proof, since I can prove it myself. What I am looking for is a elegant physical interpretation, or anything else that matches that kind of beauty.

Just to clear up, the proof I already know is

$$\int_0^1\left(1-x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8-\cdots\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}$$

So I am intersted in anything that is not obviously related to this.

Comment: What exactly is a proof without words?

Comment: @Ant, something like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712936/integral-involving-invertible-functions/712940#712940) I refer to the diagram which is sufficient on its own.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it may be possible to show this formula using Fourier series expansion of the following function $f$ periodic with period $2\pi$ such that $f(x)=\frac{π−x}{2} $ for $x∈[0;2π]$

Comment: I understand your function, how would it help?

Comment: I believe (to justify we use Dirichlet's theorem) that the fourier expansion of $f$ is $f(x)=\sum \limits_{k=1}^∞\frac{sin(kx)}{k}$, if we evaluate this function at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ ( a point where $f$ is continuous) we find your formula.

Comment: ah. very nice. +1

Comment: I cannot accept though. I want proof without words.

Answer (score 1):

$$|x|<1\implies \frac1{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\ldots\implies$$

$$\arctan x=\int\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=x-\frac13x^3+\frac15x^5-\frac17x^7+\ldots\;,\;\;\forall\,x\in(-1,1\color{red}]\;(<-- !!)\implies$$

$$\frac\pi4=\arctan 1=1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\ldots$$

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I wanted a proof without words(it might not be possible, just on the search for one). I already know this as stated at the end.

Comment: Yup, but you began with a rather non intuitive equality between an integral of infinite summands. I first show the power series of $\;\frac1{1+x^2}\;$, followed by the fact that one can integrate such a series *at least within* the convergence radius, getting a series with an extra point of convergence ($\;x=1\;$) which, finally and upon substitution of $\;x\;$ by this point, gives you the desired equality.

Comment: That's very well, I just stated it so that this answer wouldn't arise. (meaning that I am looking for alternatives,that equation was just a handwaving that I know this already). Btw, the downvote isn't mine. I'll upvote this to keep it at 0 at least.

Answer (score 0):

expand arctan(x) into taylor series:
$$
\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\cdots
$$
take x=1 and you get what you want!

Comment: This looks like what OP already knows.

Comment: um isn't that exactly what i wrote. not related to this? my integral gives the taylor series for arctan(x)

Comment: I see words...${}$