# Area enclosed by $f^{-1}(x)$ given $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

> Find the area enclosed by $g(x),x=-3,x=5$ and the $x$ axis where $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)=x^3+3x+1$.

Clearly, there's no easy way to directly find the inverse of $f(x)$.So, how to go about this? I am supposed to do this using techniques of finding area by definite integrals.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If $f\colon [a,b]\to [c,d]$ is an increasing bijection, then
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\, dx + \int_c^d f^{-1}(y)\, dy = bd - ac.
$$
(See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712936/integral-involving-invertible-functions/712940#comment1492933_712936).)

Comment: Great one: using the symmetry! I wish I had come up with this one +1

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Starting from the integral
$$\int_{-3}^5f^{-1}(x)dx$$
do the substitution $f^{-1}(x)=y$
using the derivative of inverse formula:
$$(f^{-1}(x))'=\frac1{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$
thus

$$\frac1{f'(y)}dy=dx$$

Comment: I didn't get the second part ;-(

Comment: have you tried doing the substitution?

Comment: I've added one step to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

find area enclosed between f(x) and y=x ( DEFINITE INTERGRAL)
also find area between y=x and and x axis. (trapezium)
now use the fact that f (x) and inverse if f(x) are symmetric about y=x.