# Proving $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^3}dx=\int_0^1 \sqrt[3]{1-x^2}dx$

Tags: integration

How can I prove    $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^3}dx=\int_0^1 \sqrt[3]{1-x^2}dx$$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(x) dy$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106509/is-int-ab-fx-dx-int-fafb-f-1x-dy)

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** If $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^3} $, then $ f^{-1} (x) = \sqrt[3]{1-x^2}$

Observe that $ f(0)=1, f(1)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The first integral describes the area enclosed in the first quadrant by the curve $$x^3 + y^2 = 1,$$ and the second describes the area enclosed in the first quadrant by the curve $$x^2 + y^3 = 1.$$  So with the transformation $(x,y) \to (y,x)$, it is obvious the two areas are equal.  Alternatively, we can regard both integrals as their respective double integrals:  $$\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^{\sqrt{1-x^3}} 1 \, dy \, dx = \int_{y=0}^1 \int_{x=0}^{\sqrt[3]{1-y^2}} 1 \, dx \, dy.$$

Answer (score -1):

If we take the derivative of integrals, we will get
$$\sqrt{1-x^3}=\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}$$
It is very clear the two formula are equal at $0$,$1$

Comment: This doesn't show anything.  $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=x^4-x^2$ have identical values at $\pm 1$ but $\int_{-1}^10\ dx\neq\int_{-1}^1x^4-x^2\ dx$...