# Use integration by parts to prove the equality.

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

Let $0<a<b $ and $ f: [a,b] \rightarrow [c,d]$ be an increasing bijection. Prove the following equality by area

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=bd-ac-\int_{c}^{d}f^{-1}(y)dy$.

Use integration by parts to prove the equality.

I honestly have no idea with this problem. I need full and detailed answer.

Comment: Hint: since $f$ is a bijection, try substituting $y = f(x)$ with $x = f^{-1}(y)$, and $dy = ? dx$

Comment: See the third answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106509/is-int-ab-fx-dx-int-fafb-f-1x-dy).